# Increasing resolution of Videotexture in Away3D

Tags: video, away3d

Apparently the maximum size of any Texture is 2048 pixels. But because I am using this texture inside a Sphere the image looks somewhat pixellated.

I'd like to increase the resolution somehow.
Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

2048x2048 is the maximum texture size allowed by Stage3D.

You could look at mapping to an inverted cube, like a Skybox, instead of a sphere. Then re-render the video to have 6 separate stream within the 2048 frame or even separate streams.

But keep in mind that the VideoTexture is extremely slow and inefficient in its current state. Until we have access to the decoded video frame on the GPU, it's all CPU and requires pushing each frame to the GPU on every render!